# Tensorflow object detection - own classes inference graph train/export error (tensor shape)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am new to tensorflow and object detection, and I am trying to create my own to detect 11 classes. I tried to make my own object detector using the links below.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

I have my own label_map.pbtxt file with 11 classes.

If I change the num_classes = 11 in the pipeline.config file, I have been able to train the faster rcnn resnet model, but when I try to export the model using export_inference_graph.py, I get an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [12] rhs shape= [91]
```

However, when I change the num_classes = 90 in the pipeline.config file, I can both train and export.

I'm not sure if I misunderstood something or it I shouldn't have actually changed the num_classes in the pipeline.config file.

Answer (score 0):

The number of classes in your config and pbtxt file should match. Probably this is cause of the erro

## CONFIG File

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 11
....
...
}

## PBTXT file: should have 11 entries too

item {
  id: 1
  name: 'Abyssinian'
}

item {
  id: 2
  name: 'american_bulldog'
}

item {
  id: 3
  name: 'american_pit_bull_terrier'
}
...
item {
  id: 11
  name: 'american_pit_bull_terrier'
}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However when I do have both the number of classes in the config and pbtxt file to equal 11, I still get the error:

    InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [12] rhs shape= [91]